Homemanager Option not of Type Package
I want to use nix-darwin in a modularized manner (meaning that every package is its own .nix file with all necessary options included).
However, I get an error when I execute nix build .#darwinConfigurations.atlas.system:

error: A definition for option home-manager.users.tk.home.packages."[definition 4-entry 1]"' is not of type package'.

This is my flake.nix file
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    darwin.url = "github:LnL7/nix-darwin";
    home-manager.url = "github:nix-community/home-manager";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, darwin, home-manager }:
    let
      system = "aarch64-darwin";
    in {
      darwinConfigurations.atlas = darwin.lib.darwinSystem {
        modules = [
          ./hosts/atlas.nix
        ];
        specialArgs = {
          inherit nixpkgs home-manager;
        };
      };
    };
}

This is atlas.nix
{ config, pkgs, home-manager, ... }:

let
  user = "tk";
  packageList = [
    (import ../packages/alacritty.nix { inherit pkgs; })
  ];
in
{
  imports = [
    home-manager.darwinModules.home-manager
  ];

  nixpkgs.hostPlatform = "aarch64-darwin";

  users.users.${user} = {
    name = "${user}";
    home = "/Users/${user}";
    isHidden = false;
    shell = pkgs.zsh;
  };

  home-manager = {
    useGlobalPkgs = true;
    users.${user} = {
      pkgs,
      config,
      lib,
      ...
    }: {
      home = {
        enableNixpkgsReleaseCheck = false;
        stateVersion = "23.11";
        packages = packageList;
      };
    };
  };
}

And finally alacritty.nix
{ pkgs, ... }: {
  pkgs.alacritty = {
    enable = true;
  };
}

I am pretty new to the Nix language and get tripped up a lot with the syntax. Can somebody identify the issue?

Can you try replacing packageList with just [ pkgs.alacritty ]?

Ok I got it now.
This is my flake.nix
{
  description = "Darwin configuration";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    darwin.url = "github:lnl7/nix-darwin";
    darwin.inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    home-manager.url = "github:nix-community/home-manager";
    home-manager.inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
  };

  outputs = inputs@{ nixpkgs, home-manager, darwin, ... }: {
    darwinConfigurations = {
      atlas = darwin.lib.darwinSystem {
        system = "aarch64-darwin";
        modules = [
          ./hosts/atlas.nix
          home-manager.darwinModules.home-manager
          {
            home-manager.useGlobalPkgs = true;
            home-manager.useUserPackages = true;
            home-manager.users.tk = import ./home.nix;
          }
        ];
        specialArgs = {inherit inputs;};
      };
    };
  };
}

And atlas.nix
{ config, pkgs, home-manager, ... }:
{
  nixpkgs.hostPlatform = "aarch64-darwin";
  services.nix-daemon.enable = true;
  users.users.tk = {
    name = "tk";
    home = "/Users/tk";
  };
}

home.nix
{
  inputs,
  outputs,
  lib,
  config,
  pkgs,
  home-manager,
  ...
}: {
  imports = [
    ./packages/alacritty.nix
  ];

  programs.home-manager.enable = true;
  home.stateVersion = "24.05";
}

alacritty.nix
{
  programs.alacritty = {
    enable = true;
  };
}

